# Apktool weird characters on JSON

Tags: json, unicode, apktool

So i was trying to edit an apk, decompile it using apktool and works great.
some files are readable human language but the problem is that all of the json file is unreadable with unknown symbols and characters. does someone have the knowledge on the issue? thankyou

the game has chinese character btw if that helps

[This is the image of the broken JSON file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aCA1p.png)

i tried changing the file a little bit like changing it to xml etc. but to no avail

[EDIT] Sorry i didnt put the file here,

here we go https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/folders/1fZOW-eB_3Yvh2-NwRmgZZZBTc9VHmX6N

Comment: Are you certain it's actually JSON and not some obfuscated or encrypted format that the devs stuck into a file whose name ends in `.json`?

Comment: We can do nothing with an image.